# Extension of an identity related to a Dirichlet series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $F(\sigma+it)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n n^{-(\sigma+it)}$ a Dirichlet series that is absolutely convergent in the half-plane $\sigma>\sigma_a$ and let $G(\sigma+it)$ be a function such that
$$F(\sigma)=G(\sigma),$$
for all $\sigma>\sigma_a$.

In this general setting is it true that $F(\sigma+it)=G(\sigma+it)$, in the half-plane $\sigma>\sigma_a$?

Comment: What do a know about $G$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it is a product of a Dirichlet series  with an integral depending on this  same DS.